# Discrete centre of Lie group

Tags: lie-groups

Can the centre of a (compact, semisimple) Lie group $G$ be discrete? If yes, under which conditions on $G$ this happens? Any references would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $G$ is a compact semisimple Lie group, then its center $Z_G$ is always discrete. This is because if $\mathfrak{g}$ is the Lie algebra of $G$, then
$$\mathrm{Lie}(Z_G)=Z_{\mathfrak{g}},$$
the center of $\mathfrak{g}$. But $Z_{\mathfrak{g}}=\{0\}$ since $\mathfrak{g}$ is semisimple. (This is because $Z_{\mathfrak{g}}$ is an abelian ideal, so also a solvable ideal.)

Comment: Thank's! Do you have any reference in mind?

Comment: @user3257624 I don't know if you can find that specific statement, but a general good reference for Lie groups and Lie algebras is Knapp *Lie groups beyond an introduction*.

Comment: Would that be Proposition 7.9?

Comment: @user3257624 That's a much stronger result with strong assumptions. Why do you need a reference? It's better to just understand the simple argument above there. Every ingredient used in that proof can be found in the book though. Is there some part you don't understand?

Comment: @user3257624 You can find the statement as a remark below Proposition 6.30 on page 361.

Comment: @user3257624 Note that we don't need $G$ to be compact. But if it is compact, then $Z_G$ is actually finite. This is because a closed subgroup of a compact space is compact and a compact discrete space is finite.

Comment: Great, I found that remark! Thank you very much. I need a refernce for my thesis and I don't want to prove the statement myself, because my topic is not reated to Group theory.